Apex batch class with multiple Start or Execute method with different SOQL methods and different schedule time
I need to create a scheduled batch apex class that would generate NBA(Next Best Actions) of type Call and Email, based on different SOQL querylocator and their scheduled time would be different and to be fetched from a custom metadatatype, for example, Call NBA batch should be scheduled every week, where as Email NBA should be scheduled twice a week, how can I have a single apex batch class, but the Start and execute method needs to be parameterized and their scheduled time should be parameterized.
Like below -
Batch class X
Query1 = targeted Account and Users for Call NBA
Query2 = targeted Account and Users for Email NBA
Cron for Call = 'every week pattern'
Cron for Email = 'twice a week pattern'
System.scheduleBatch = X(Query1), Cron for Call
System.scheduleBatch = X(Query2), Cron for Email

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Without this detail, your question is likely to be closed without answer.
